# Pyodbc not showing any drivers as installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc

Hoping somebody can point in the right direction here.

I have a python program I developed on my Windows PC. Everything works great. However, I need to migrate this to a server/Xubuntu VM and it no longer connects to the db. I know this is an issue with the driver name I have configured, because I was able to get it to connect in the past, by viewing the drivers available with pyodbc.drivers().

Python version is 3.7.5. Running in pipenv virtual environment. All dependencies are installed. Same config in windows and it works. POSTGRESQL is installed locally along with pgadmin4.

```
import pyodbc

print(pyodbc.drivers())
```

returns 'pyodbc' has no attribute drivers

```
print(pyodbc.version)
```

also returns 'pyodbc' has no attribute version.

```
odbcinst -j
```

returns the following:

```
unixODBC 2.3.6
DRIVERS..........: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
```

However cat/nano /etc/odbcinst.ini does not show anything, like the file is empty.

I just need to know the name of the ODBC driver installed to use with the pyodbc connection!

Comment: *"I just need to know the name of the ODBC driver"* - If you are getting `AttributeError: module 'pyodbc' has no attribute 'version'` then your problem is deeper than that; your pyodbc install is broken.

Comment: You're right, I believe it to be an issue with python versions. The program was written in a pipenv for 3.7 but the server im migrating to is running 3.8. Every time I try to roll back the version of Python running on the server it breaks pip, pipenv, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing and re-installing pyodbc, and then installing odbc-postgresql, which resolved my issue:

```
apt-get install odbc-postgresql
```